# How to hold event graphs until another event is completed

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint, unreal

I am kind of new to unreal. Let me try to explain my use case and my issue.

Currently I have 4 assets: 1- Blueprint User input textbox, where users can write their own text; 2- BP_ThirdPerson Character (standard one), I have an event graph where when you hit “E” overlapping with an NPC, it will build the widget from 1-, and call to another blueprint that I use as interface for 3-. ; 3-Blueprint NPC, generic manny that when 2- pipeline finished, it triggers to print some standard phrases on a widget 4-; 4-Blueprint Standard text widget to display the phrases from 3-.

The thing is that for this to work, all the steps of triggering the interface on asset 2-, I should be waiting until user commits text on widget 1-. I will be passing values of variables between assets but that I kind of solved it. My issue mainly is on asset 2-, to wait until user commits text on asset 1- before it ends up in the blueprint that I use as interface on asset 3-.

Any help would be appreciated!